# Proof there is a 1-1 correspondence between an uncountable set and itself minus a countable part of it

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem statement:**

Let A be an uncountable set, B a countable subset of A, and C the complement of B in A.  Prove that there exists a one-to-one correspondence between A and C.

**My thoughts:**

There's a bijection between A and A (the identity function).  There's a bijection between C and C (the identity function).  There's a bijection between B and $\mathbb{N}$.  That's all I know.

Comment: I take it you don't have cardinal arithmetic on hand yet?

Comment: Cardinal numbers are in the next chapter, so I guess not.  This chapter proves that a countable union of countable sets is countable, $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, the algebraic numbers are countable, and $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $A\setminus B$ is uncountable, assuming countable choice it has a countably infinite subset $B'$.  Then $B'\cup B$ is countable, so there is a bijection $g:B'\cup B\to B'$.  Define $f:A\to A\setminus B$ by $f\vert_{B'\cup B}=g$ and $f(a)=a$ for $a\in A\setminus(B'\cup B)$.

Basically, you just take chunks off of $A$ and $A\setminus B$ that have equal size, respectively $B'\cup B$ and $B'$, leaving the remaining sets equal to $A\setminus(B'\cup B)$, then piece together the two bijections.