# Bijective mapping from a infinite set

Tags: metric-spaces

How do we define this mapping:

Let $A$ be a infinite set and let $B \subset A$.  Suppose that $B$ is finite.  Show that there exists a bijective mapping $ $  $f: A \rightarrow A\setminus B$

We get a hint: Use denumeration $B = \left\{ b_1, b_2, ...,b_n \right\}$

Comment: Is the set *countably* infinite or just not finite?

Comment: I assume that it is not finite according to our defenitions

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25241/proof-there-is-a-1-1-correspondence-between-an-uncountable-set-and-itself-minus. I will be the first to admit I didn't believe the assertion at first for the uncountable case but failed to find a counterexample. Evidently it *is* true.

Comment: This cannot be done without the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is countably infinite, write
$$
A = \{a_{1} = b_{1}, a_{2} = b_{2}, \ldots, a_{n} = b_{n}, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \ldots \} = B \cup \{ a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \ldots \}
$$
and define $f(a_{k}) = a_{k + n}$.